# Irreducibility of the following Polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Take the polynomial $x^4 + 10x^2 + 1$. Is this irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? If so, what is the best way to show this? I know it can be rewritten:
$$
(x^2 + 5)^2 -24
$$
Which can be simplified over the irrationals, but not over $\mathbb{Q}$. How could I use this to show irreducibility? (if it has anything to do with it)

Comment: [Here is a key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Comment: You can find the roots of your polynomial by doing $x^2 =t$. Then if non of those 4 roots are rational then the only posibility for  the polynomial to be reducible is by a grade 2 polynomial which has to have 2 of the roots you found as solution. Showing that those polynomial are not in $Q$ ends the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: After checking there are no rational roots, you can look for factors of the form $x^2 + a x \pm 1$.  Note also that if $p(x)$ is a factor, so is $p(-x)$.